# Python multiprocessing ImportError

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I’m having trouble using python’s multiprocessing module. This is the first time I’ve tried using the module. I’ve tried simplifying my processing to the bare bones, but keep getting the same error. I’m using python 2.7.2, and Windows 7.

The script I’m trying to run is called `learnmp.py`, and the error message says that the problem is that it can't find module `learnmp`.

```
import multiprocessing

def doSomething():
    """worker function"""
    print 'something'
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':

    jobs = []
    for i in range(2):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=doSomething)
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

The error is :

```
File “<string>”, line 1, in <module> File “C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.1\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py”, line 373,
in main prepare(preparation_data) File “C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.1\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py”, line 482,
in prepare file, path_name, etc = imp.find_module (main_name, dirs)
ImportError: No module named learnmp
```

What’s causing the error, and how can I solve it?

EDIT: I still don't know what was causing the error, but changing the file name eliminated it.

Comment: Well, for one thing, your indentation is off - as posted, the `if __name__ ...` clause is part of your `doSomething()` function, not top-level code as it should be. `p.start() jobs.append(p)` on the same line is likely to be problematic as well. And your error messages don't appear to be coming from the code you posted...

Comment: I fixed the indentation. That was poor proofreading, not the non-functioning code.

Comment: `print(sys.path)` and make sure that it prints expected directories. Are there multiple `learnmp` modules in `sys.path`?

Comment: I know this might be obvious, but how are you running the script? From another script, or the command line?

Answer (score 4):

I know it's been a while, but I ran into this same error, also using the version of Python distributed with ArcGIS, and I've found a solution which at least worked in my case.

The problem that I had was that I was calling my program name, Test.py, as test.py. Note the difference in case.

```
c:\python27\arcgisx6410.2\python.exe c:\temp\test.py
c:\python27\arcgisx6410.2\python.exe c:\temp\Test.py
```

This isn't normally an issue if you're not using the multiprocessing library. However, when you write:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

what appears to be happening is that the part of the program in main is being bound to the name of the python file. In my case that was test. However, there is no test, just Test. So although Windows will allow case-incorrect filenames in cmd, PowerShell, and in batch files, Python's multiprocessing library balks at this and throws a nasty series of errors.

Hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be going down a rabbit-hole looking into `multiprocessing`. As the traceback shows, your python install is trying to look in the ArcGIS version of python before actually looking at your system install.

My guess is that the version of python that ships with ArcGIS is slightly customized for some reason or another and can't find your python script. The question then becomes:

> Why is your Windows machine looking in ArcGIS for python?

Without looking at your machine at a slightly lower level I can't quite be sure, but if I had to guess, you probably added the ArcGIS directory to your `PATH` variable in front of the standard python directory, so it looks in ArcGIS first. If you move the ArcGIS path to the end of your `PATH` variable it should resolve the problem.

Changing your `PATH` variable: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required for some python modules to work in windows,so download below package it will work.

`http://aka.ms/vcpython27`

This package contains the compiler and set of system headers necessary for producing binary wheels for Python 2.7 packages.